# Unexpected behaviour when programmatically toggling exceptions in Android P and Q Beta

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-9.0-pie, android-10.0

I have a very simple app, with one button. When I press this button, I want both "From starred contacts only" and "Play media sounds" to be toggled programmatically. The code I am using is:

```
private void setPolicyStarredContacts() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.setNotificationPolicy(
            new NotificationManager.Policy(PRIORITY_CATEGORY_MEDIA,
                    NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_SENDERS_STARRED,
                    NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_SENDERS_ANY));

}
```

What actually happens is that only "Play media sounds" gets activated, but not the other option. I'd be grateful for some indication of what I am doing wrong. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have actually found the answer! Here it is for future searchers:

```
private void setPolicyStarredContacts() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.setNotificationPolicy(
            new NotificationManager.Policy(PRIORITY_CATEGORY_CALLS | PRIORITY_CATEGORY_MEDIA,
                    NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_SENDERS_STARRED,
                    NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_SENDERS_ANY));

}
```